# Determine whether a set is a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a h.W question.

For each of the following, determine if the set is a subring of the real
numbers. Explain your answer in both cases.

a) $\{ a + b \sqrt[3]{5} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

b)  $\{ a + b\sqrt[3]{5}  + c\sqrt[3]{25} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

For both of these I believe they are subrings as they the equations form a subset of $R$ (I think) and

1)for $a=0$, $b=0$ we have $(0+0)=0$

2) for any a,b,c and d,e,f  $ (a+d) + (b+e)\sqrt[3]{5}  + (c+f)\sqrt[3]{25}$

3) finally for every  $a + b\sqrt[3]{5}  + c\sqrt[3]{25}$ part of the subset of R  then $-(a + b\sqrt[3]{5}  + c\sqrt[3]{25})$ is also part of subset

I have a strong feeling I might be wrong because this seems too easy and my Prof doesnt ask easy questions.

Comment: Where you wrote $a,b E Z$, did you mean $a,b\in Z$?

Comment: yes I did, I couldnt figure how to get the element sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variables are integers, a fails because multiplication is not closed.  If you multiply $(a+b\sqrt[3]5)(c+d\sqrt[3]5)$ what do you get?  Try to express it as $e+f\sqrt[3]5$.  This will show you why b works.

Comment: I have got two hints both indicating I look at multiplication. Indeed if I multiply $(a+b\sqrt[3]{5})*(c+ d\sqrt[3]{5})$ I get $(ac+(ad+bc) \sqrt[3]{5} + bd*5^{3/2}$ but forgive me as rings are really new topic for me. Why do I need to check closure under multiplication for a subring.

Comment: IS it that I have to show that the given sets (a) and (b) are Rings first.

Comment: Sorry didnt read the Theorem correctly. It mentioned xy and x+y must also be in the subring.

Comment: @KjTada:  Yes, that is the point.  Products fail for a, but work for b.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$(a)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sqrt[3] 5\cdot \sqrt[3] 5=\sqrt[3]{5^2}=5^{3/2}\ldots$$

Comment: The last one should be $5^{2/3}$